# Add WooCommerce custom checkout fields if there is only non virtual items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, virtual, checkout

Have a script in my functions.php to show certain custom fields I created to appear at checkout, but some products do not need these fields to appear. So I assigned these as virtual and used this code to make these only appear on standard products:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'my_checkout_fields' );
function my_checkout_fields( $checkout ) {

    $only_virtual = false;

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
      if ( ! $cart_item['data']->is_virtual() ) $only_virtual = true;   
   }
 
    if( $only_virtual ) {

    woocommerce_form_field( 'so_childs_name', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'required'      => 'true',
        'class'         => array('cname-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Child&#39;s Name'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'so_childs_name' ));
}
```

It works.... occasionally.

Of course, I need it to work all the time, so why isn't it working or is there is a way instead of using only_virtual, can I just use an array of product ID's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistake and a missing closing bracket in your code *(if I have well understood)*. Try:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'my_checkout_fields' );
function my_checkout_fields( $checkout ) {
    $has_virtual = false; // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( $cart_item['data']->is_virtual() ) {
            $has_virtual = true; // Stop the loop
            break;
        }
    }

    if( ! $has_virtual ) {
        woocommerce_form_field( 'so_childs_name', array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'required'      => 'true',
            'class'         => array('cname-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Child&#39;s Name'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'so_childs_name' ) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't. Still experiencing the same issues.

Comment: Oh, wait. I think it is working. Give me a couple days to be sure because my previous code actually worked for me but some customers, it didn;t.